# No color profile found for RGB screen colors

Tags: errors, ubuntu, color-profile

I am using Texmaker and when building tex file I get the following error:

> No color profile found for RGB screen colors

The files is compiled correctly, it seems that the Texmaker has issue with some missing color profile. Also this only happens when I use `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`. It points to this lines of code (inside file **pdfx.sty**), where the loading fails:

```
%%  PDF/A  needs an RGB color profile for on-screen rendering
\IfFileExists{\pdfx@rgb@profile}{%
  \immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 3^^J/Alternate/DeviceRGB} file{\pdfx@rgb@profile}%
  \edef\OBJ@RGB{\the\pdflastobj}%
}{%
  \errmessage{No color profile found to use for RGB screen colors.}%
}%
```

I am using Ubuntu 15.10, therefore is it possible that I am missing some packages? I tried to install everything that I could find for Ubuntu regarding ICC color profiles, but without much success.

Comment: It is hard to provide help without seeing the code you are compiling. A minimal example should be provided in all (very-nearly-absolutely-all) questions. But, are you including a PNG or other external image by any chance? If so, does the error resolve if you omit it?

Comment: It only matters if I include the following package `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`. Also pdf is compiled correctly in the case of error, it seems that only Texmaker has issues with displaying PDF/A compliant file.

Comment: You said you got the error when building, but now you say you get it only when viewing the resulting PDF. So there's no compilation error? And you haven't said if you are using any PNG or not. But, if so, an incorrect PNG is probably to blame. Some software is much stricter about the PNG specifications than others. (Can't see why use of **pdfx** would affect this, though.) I guess you probably don't need an answer very badly since you don't supply a minimal example, but still, if it is worth asking the question, it might be worth providing enough that somebody might be able to answer it.

Comment: Yes, I am including the images but as I have specified in my opening question, this error occurs outside my own files (`pdfx.sty`), that is why the use of **pdfx** affects this. I will add the name of the file where error occurs to the question, but as this is outside my control, it is independent of some minimal example, except that I am using package `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}`.

Comment: @cfr I have updated the description of the problem. Let me clarify that I was at first not aware that the file is being compiled correctly, as I normally use the internal PDF browser of the TexMaker and that one was not displaying any changes. So now we can see, that this is probably due to some missing ICC color profile, which **pdfx** needs to display correctly.

Comment: I think you have to correct the PNG.

Comment: You can have a look [at this page](http://www.color.org/srgbprofiles.xalter)